# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I write the following stored procedure in `sql server 2008` i am getting the error as i mentioned i don't know why so can any one resolve this

```
create PROCEDURE dbo.uspTest1
as
    declare @cnt int;
    declare @cnt1 int;
    declare @cnt2 int;

     set @cnt=(SELECT COUNT(EmpID) AS Expr1 FROM tblTest WHERE (FedTaxID = '888888888') AND (TaxTypeCode = 'TX02'))

set @cnt1=(SELECT COUNT(EmpID) AS Expr1 FROM tblTest
WHERE(FedTaxID = '888888888') AND (TaxTypeCode = 'TX03'))
set @cnt2=(SELECT 
    TaxTypeCode, SUM(Amount) 
FROM 
    tblTest 
WHERE
    FedTaxID = '888888888'
    AND TaxTypeCode IN ('TX02', 'TX03')
GROUP BY
    TaxTypeCode)
```

This is the another one i tried this is also giving an error for me

```
create PROCEDURE dbo.uspTest1
as
    declare @cnt int;
    declare @cnt1 int;
    declare @cnt2 int;

     set @cnt=(SELECT     COUNT(EmpID) AS Expr1
FROM         tblTest
WHERE     (FedTaxID = '888888888') AND (TaxTypeCode = 'TX02'))

set @cnt1=(SELECT     COUNT(EmpID) AS Expr1
FROM         tblTest
WHERE     (FedTaxID = '888888888') AND (TaxTypeCode = 'TX03'))

set @cnt2=(SELECT  SUM(Txallt) as txnntot
  FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN  TaxTypeCode = 'tx02' THEN Amount else 0 END as tx02t,
               CASE WHEN  TaxTypeCode = 'tx03' THEN Amount else 0 END as tx03t,
               Amount as txallt
        FROM tbltest
        WHERE FedTaxID = '888888888'
       ))
GROUP BY FedTaxId
```

`This is giving an error as Incorrect Syntax near ')'`

So can any one tell what's wrong i am doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply take out the TaxTypeCode in the first one

```
set @cnt2=(SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) 
FROM 
    tblTest 
WHERE
    FedTaxID = '888888888'
    AND TaxTypeCode IN ('TX02', 'TX03')
GROUP BY
    TaxTypeCode)
```

However SUM(Amount)..GROUP BY will return multiple rows but you are trying to assign to one variable: one row in the result will be picked arbitrarily for @cnt2

Do you need GROUP BY?

If not, you can make this a lot simpler:

```
SELECT
   @cnt = COUNT(CASE TaxTypeCode = 'TX02' THEN EmpID ELSE NULL END),
   @cnt1 = COUNT(CASE TaxTypeCode = 'TX03' THEN EmpID ELSE NULL END),
   @cnt2 = SUM(Amount)
FROM
   tblTest
WHERE
   FedTaxID = '888888888'
   AND
   TaxTypeCode IN ('TX02', 'TX03')
```

Otherwise, add sample data and clear description of what you are trying to do...

Comment: @Dorababu: you're welcome! Out of interest, what bits of my answer did you use please?

Comment: `@gbn` the second one with out `group by`

Answer (score 2):

In the first, the problem is this line:

```
set @cnt2=(SELECT TaxTypeCode, SUM(Amount) FROM tblTest 
WHERE FedTaxID = '888888888' AND TaxTypeCode IN ('TX02', 'TX03') 
GROUP BY TaxTypeCode)
```

You are trying to set a variable to a query that is selecting 2 columns, you can only set it to a value that returns 1 row with 1 column.

---

In the second, you are creating a sub query that is returning a table, so you need an alias.  Change

```
WHERE FedTaxID = '888888888'
         ))
```

to be

```
WHERE FedTaxID = '888888888'
         ) x )
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub-queries need an alias.  This is the reason for the error "Incorrect syntax near ')'".

For example, this query does not have an alias, so running it gives the same "Incorrect syntax" error:

```
declare @x int
set @x = (select count(*) from (select * from sys.objects))
```

You can fix the above statement by including an alias for the sub-query:

```
declare @x int
set @x = (select count(*) from (select * from sys.objects) AllSysObjects)
select @x
```

Comment: I disagree I use select when setting multiple variables, otherwise use set.  Here's a good article on differences http://vyaskn.tripod.com/differences_between_set_and_select.htm